# The letter "a" doesn't seem to come out after a certain point in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

So I'm doing a question where the function counts repeating characters and prints them out. I do get the right solution, but what ends up happening is that the letter a doesn't get counted since it showed up before.

So here's the code

```
fun sCompression(s: String): String{
    var solution = ""
    var count = 1

  for (i in 0 until s.length - 1){
      if (s[i] == s[i + 1]){
          count++
      }else{
         solution = solution.plus("${s[i]}$count")
          count = 1
      }

  }
    return solution

}
```

Here are the inputs

[image]

And There Outputs

[image]

Expected output

Out1:a2b3c6a5

Out2:a1c1a1c1b1a4

Out3:a2b3c6d11u6x2

P.S. as you can see, the x in the last input also doesn't show up either. Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Can you show the *expected* outputs? I don't understand what the code is *supposed* to do here.

Comment: You are only modifying the solution if a different character is encountered. You should also do that at the end of the input line.

Comment: What do you mean by "the end of the input line"?

Comment: Think about the last iteration of the loop, where `i` is `s.length - 1`.  Does the count for the last character always get added to `solution` in that iteration?

Comment: No it does not. But I had to do that to avoid the out of bounds exception.

Comment: So the problem isn't `s.length - 1` (you'd get an out of bounds exception if it was `s.length`, like you say).  The problem is that the code needs to make sure that on the last iteration of the loop, it always adds the count of the last character to `solution`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, you are appending a new run length encoding `${s[i]}$count"` only when `s[i] != s[i + 1]`. Notice that this condition is never true for the *last* "segment' of the same characters.

Consider a string with 3 "segments" with the same characters. I have annotated the positions of the index `i` where the condition `s[i] != s[i + 1]` would be true:

```
aaaaabbbbbbccccccc
    ^     ^
```

There are only 2 locations, in a string with 3 "segments"! In the first location, you append "a5", and in the second location, you append "b6", and that's it.

Basically, you need to also handle the last "segment" of the string. When you reach the end of the loop, you would have already counted the length of this segment using the variable `count`. All you need to do is to append to `solution`.

```
// after the loop:
val last = s.lastOrNull()
if (last != null) { // to handle the case of empty strings
    solution += "${last}$count" // you can use "+=", no need to call .plus
}
```

You can also do this with a string builder, which can be more efficient:

```
fun sCompression(s: String) = buildString {
    var count = 1

    for (i in 0 until s.length - 1){
        if (s[i] == s[i + 1]){
            count++
        }else{
            append("${s[i]}$count")
            count = 1
        }
    }
    val last = s.lastOrNull()
    if (last != null) {
        append("${last}$count")
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't account for null with the last character. After the loop is finished, the last character is being compared to a null value. So nothing comes of it. That makes so much sense. Thank You. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @OEThe11 ah I see why you were confused. No, Kotlin strings are not null-terminated.

Comment: I did not know that. That's definitely good know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach where you don't need any special case handling, using a *fold*:

```
// made count a var so we can just update it
data class Repeat(val char: Char, var count: Int)

input.fold(mutableListOf<Repeat>()) { repeats, c ->
    if (repeats.lastOrNull()?.char != c) repeats.add(Repeat(c, 0))
    repeats.apply { last().count++ }
}.joinToString("") { "${it.char}${it.count}" }.run(::println)
```

It's building a list of `Repeat`s that represent a `Char` and how many of them are in the sequence. It looks at the most recent `Repeat` added to the list, and compares its `char` to the current character. If it doesn't match (or there isn't a `Repeat` in the list because this is the first character) it creates a new `Repeat` for this `Char` to start a new sequence, and adds it to the list.

At that point the last `Repeat` in the list represents the current character, and we just increment its count (and the list is passed to the next iteration of the `fold` since it's the last value expressed).

So the difference here is instead of looking forward in the collection to compare, you're looking at the results of your previous work (in this case it holds the most recent character and its current streak) and deciding what to do from that. And each iteration adds to that accumulated data - when it's finished, you just need to transform it all. You don't need to account for certain iterations adding to the result (e.g. when you see a character change) and handle edge cases where that gets "interrupted".

---

This might be kinda overdoing it for what you're doing (and it's not efficient for extremely large strings or large numbers of them - you could do a version with a `StringBuilder` as the accumulator though!) but it's more to show the general principle, and it can be a good fit for more complex data. It's also a common way to take something that uses *recursion* and rework it to use *iteration* instead